# SharePoint 2010 - StoragePoint missing EndPoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, remote-blob-store

I'm trying to get rid of StoragePoint from my 2010 farm. I've recalled all the content but some timer jobs are throwing errors because of ONE item. The errors are like the following:

> Error encountered in Profile.ProviderRetrieveBinary. Error is Cannot
>   find specified EndPointId: endpoint
>
> Recall Item Failed For Doc Version in SiteId = 'siteid' with ItemId =
>   'itemid' UIVersion: 512. Error was: Cannot find specified EndPointId:
>   endpoint

I've actually looked all through the StoragePoint database and can't find the EndPoint ID in question (maybe just not the right query). The document ID exists in AllDocs table in the content database, and we downloaded the document and deleted it from SharePoint, but it still remains in the database, even after deleting it from the recycle bin.

I don't care about this document and I would just uninstall storagepoint but there are other functions which are not updating properly and it revolves around this error, so therefore I'm afraid to go ahead in case this is just a game-breaking error that I need to resolve before I can get all my content retracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who may have this problem:

1. I was able to search the databases and find out that the item
   mentioned in the errors above was still available in my document
   library.
2. I downloaded the file to local storage
3. I deleted the file from SharePoint and cleared it out of the recycle
   bin
4. I then, thanks to an MVP, realized I had not deleted it from the
   Site Collection recycle bin, and deleted it from there, too.
5. Then, ran the recall job and the unused blob cleanup job again and
   everything went perfectly
6. I deleted the storage profile
7. Later on I'm going to remove StoragePoint